# Converting static linked library to dynamic linked library under windows

Tags: dll

I am in the midst of evaluating the benefits of changing our program from 30+ statically linked libraries to 30+ dynamically linked libraries.  We hope by changing to DLL, it will reduce the link time.

One immediate problem is the requirement to add __declspec in front of all the classes to create the lib file for other dlls to link.  Is there a way to get around that?  Is there a flag in the compiler to force a lib generation so to make all classes inside the DLL available for export?  If not, is there any existing script/program that will do that? That will certainly make the switch from statically linked library to a dynamic one a lot easier.  If not, what is the rationale behind __declspec?  Why not an option to make all dll functions exportable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's too late, but have you looked into using a [DEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) file?

Answer (score 0):

There is one another way to solve your problem.

You just need to create one definition file(.def) and export all the methods or class you want to share.

U will also have to set :
Properties->Linker->Input->Module Definition File -> add name of your  created .def file.

Now use run time dynamic linking:
In project where you want to call the exported methods use LoadLibrary to get handle of your Dll and call the required method using GetProcAddress.